# Processing xml file (Java)

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, xerces

I have to read and xml file, do some changes, and copy it to another location. I also have to keep the german special characters, and keep the empty tags as they are (prevent them to become self-closing tags). For preventing the self closing tags, I used Xerces Library, as in the link:
[preventing empty xml elements are converted to self closing elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588555/preventing-empty-xml-elements-are-converted-to-self-closing-elements)

In my application, if my changes in xml are ignored, the code looks like:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\qwe.xml"));
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"ISO-8859-1");
    InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
    is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
    dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
    doc.setXmlStandalone(true);

    File file = new File ("D:\\qwerty.xml");
    XMLStreamWriter writer = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1") ;
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StAXResult(writer));
```

}

The first row in the source file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The problem is in the destination file, qwerty.xml, where  encoding="UTF-8" is removed. In the source file, although the encoding is UTF-8, I had to set it as "ISO-8859-1" because of german characters. I want to keep the first row as the original, keep the empty tags as they are (not self-closing tags), and keep the german characters. My code succeeds to do only the second and third thing.

Answer (score 0):

The call

```
Transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
```

has no effect unless the transformer is producing serialized output.

In your case the transformer is not producing serialized output because you are sending the output to a StAXResult. I'm not sure why you are using the XmlStreamWriter to produce output, but if you want to do it that way, it's the XmlStreamWriter that decides on the encoding, not the Transformer.

I would have thought it was simpler to send the Transformer output to a StreamResult.

Comment: XmlStreamWriter is the only way I found to keep the empty tags as they are (I don't want to transform them in self-closing tags). This is the only reason I use it.

Comment: Well, if you want an XmlStreamWriter to do the serializing, then you must tell it what encoding to use. (You haven't said why you don't want self-closing tags. If the receiving application can't handle them then your whole system is incredibly fragile. Rewrite it to use a conformant XML parser, rather than trying to pander to its weaknesses.)

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem and still no solution... I "have to" use `StAXResult` instead of `StreamResult` to force full closing tags on XML empty elements (not self-closing tags), because I sent my XML to an external system that doesn't handle self-closing tags (and I don't have the hand on it, can't modify it). The problem is that every property (like encoding) put on the `Transformer` is ignored. If I use writeStartDocument to write the encoding, I have also the start `<xml` tag from the Transformer, as I can't ask to omit it with its `OMIT_XML_DECLARATION` property... crazy!

Comment: If you're doing the serializing yourself, rather than letting XSLT do it, then obviously instructions to XSLT about how to do the serialization are going to be ignored. Doesn't seem crazy at all to me. What's crazy is that you are having to deal with someone who is trying to read your XML without using a conformant XML parser.