# Avoid to generate XML self-closing tags for empty elements AND generate a custom <xml> start tag

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I need to generate a XML file with some data to send to a 3rd-party system I don't have the hands on (made by another company and I can't modify it or ask to modify it)

This other system doesn't accept my generated document because it has some self-closing tags for empty elements : `<tag/>` instead of `<tag></tag>`

My current code lokks like that

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(file);
transformer.transform(source, streamResult);
```

To generate full-closing tags, I tried to ask the `Transformer` to use the `html` output method :

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
```

*source: http://makble.com/the-self-closing-tag-problem-of-javaxxmltransform-package-dom-to-source*

This works to have full-closing tags, BUT I have other problems :

- the XML document starting tag is not generated (like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>`)
- the special characters are generated in an HTML way (like `&eacute;` instead of `é`)

So I found that I could use a `StAXResult` instead of `StreamResult` like that :

```
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        XMLStreamWriter writer = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(nomFichier)));
        StAXResult streamResult = new StAXResult(writer);
        transformer.transform(source, streamResult);
```

This also works to have full closing tags on empty elements, but my XML document starting tag is incomplete :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

If I try to define it using the Transformer's output properties, this does not work :

```
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "no");
```

All properties are ignored because of the usage of the `StAXResult`

This is clearly said in [Processing xml file (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605492/processing-xml-file-java) by Michael Kay (https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay) :

> The call `Transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");` has no effect unless the transformer is producing
> serialized output. In your case the transformer is not producing
> serialized output because you are sending the output to a StAXResult

I the tried to configure the `XMLStreamWriter` at least to define the encoding :

```
        XMLStreamWriter writer = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(nomFichier)));
        writer.writeStartDocument("ISO-8859-1", "1.0");
        StAXResult streamResult = new StAXResult(writer);
        transformer.transform(source, streamResult);
```

This leads to add the "correct" starting XML tag but I also have the default one from the Transformer :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Finally I retried to remove the Transformer default tag :

```
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
```

But as already said this doesn't work because Transformer's output properties are ignored...

**Any ideas about how I can achieve to have both all these?**

- a valid XML starting tag (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>`)
- correct characters encoding (`é` and not `&eacute;`)
- full closing tags when the element is empty (`<tag></tag>` instead of `<tag/>`)

The only way I see is to write the document using `XMLStreamWriter` and `StAXResult`, then process the generated file to parse it and remove the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` element and replace it with a hard-coded `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` string, but I don't really want to parse my generated XML file just for that as it could be quite big.

I'm looking for a more elegant solution !

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a StAXResult if you want to create a file? As you mention in your answer, you are transforming one tree structure into another tree structure. The XML is never serialized and the serialization settings are therefore not taken into account.

Your main issue seems to be that you want to avoid self-closing tags, but this makes no sense, since self-closing tags are semantically identical to a pair of opening/closing tags. The only workaround I think is using XSLT in which you trick the processor into writing an opening and closing tag by adding some content that will not produce any output in between. But this will presumably also depend on your processor. In the end you are trying to send XML to a system that can't understand XML, so you will always have to resort to hacks.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid XML self-closing tags, you can use

```
@JsonProperty(value = "TEST")
@JsonSerializer(nullsUsing = NullSerializer.class)
private String test;
```

NullSerializer: it will be a class which extends from JsonSerializer, and it will return null.

So, if "test" variable is null, the generated XML message will look as following:

```
<TEST></TEST>
```

instead of:

```
<TEST/>
```

Comment: the problem is that I can't use variables with annotations like that, as I generate dynamically the XML content from structured objects coming from the database:          `Element tag = document.createElement("mytag");
            tag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(object.getXXX() != null ? object.getXXX().toString() : ""));` If I have to set each value I generate into a class variable this will be super heavy... :-/