# Jackson XML: how to serialize empty/null collections as empty node

Tags: java, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm using Jackson XML 2.8.9 and unfortunately I cannot find any way to serialize empty/null collections as empty nodes.

Method responsible for serializing to XML:

```
protected byte[] toXml(final Collection<ReportView> reports) throws IOException
{
    final XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
    // place for code which will solve my problem
    return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().withRootName("report").writeValueAsBytes(reports);
}
```

I tried to use:

- serialization inclusion:

  ```
  mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);
  ```
- serialization provider:

  ```
  final XmlSerializerProvider provider = new XmlSerializerProvider(new XmlRootNameLookup());
  provider.setNullValueSerializer(new JsonSerializer<Object>()
  {
      @Override
      public void serialize(final Object value, final JsonGenerator jgen, final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException
      {
          jgen.writeString("");
      }
  });
  mapper.setSerializerProvider(provider);
  ```
- Jackson 2.9.0 EMPTY_ELEMENT_AS_NULL feature:

  ```
  mapper.configure(FromXmlParser.Feature.EMPTY_ELEMENT_AS_NULL, false);
  ```

Unfortunately nothing works. Does anybody know how to achieve it?

Test method:

```
@Test
public void testToXml() throws IOException
{
    final Map<String, Object> payload = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    payload.put("amp", "&");
    payload.put("empty", Collections.emptyList());
    final Date date = new Date();
    final ReportView reportView = new ReportView(payload, date, "system");

    // when
    final byte[] xmlBytes = reportService.toXml(Arrays.asList(reportView));

    // then
    final StringBuilder expected = new StringBuilder();
    expected.append("<report>");
    expected.append("  <item>");
    expected.append("    <payload>");
    expected.append("      <amp>&amp;</amp>");
    expected.append("      <empty></empty>");
    expected.append("    </payload>");
    expected.append("    <timestamp>" + date.getTime() + "</timestamp>");
    expected.append("    <changingUser>system</changingUser>");
    expected.append("  </item>");
    expected.append("</report>");

    final String xmlText = new String(xmlBytes).replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
    assertThat(xmlText).isEqualTo(expected.toString());
}
```

`ReportView` class:

```
public class ReportView {
    private final Map<String, Object> payload;
    private final Date timestamp;
    private final String changingUser;

    public ReportView(Map<String, Object> payload, Date timestamp, String changingUser) {
        this.payload = payload;
        this.timestamp= timestamp;
        this.changingUser = changingUser;
    }

    public String getChangingUser() {
        return changingUser;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }
}
```

I prepared a repository with example code: https://github.com/agabrys/bugs-reports/tree/master/jackson-xml/empty-elements-serialization

---

EDIT:

I extended the test `toXml` method and did some code cleanup.

I also tried to create a solution based on `Module` and `SerializerModifier`. Unfortunately both ended with failure. I created an issue in `jackson-dataformat-xml` backlog:

- [NPE after overriding map serializer with custom implementation (XmlBeanSerializerModifier.modifyMapSerializer)](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/259)

---

EDIT:

I've got a hint how to solve problem with exception (see [NPE after overriding map serializer with custom implementation (XmlBeanSerializerModifier.modifyMapSerializer)](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/259)) but still it does not solve problem with missing `empty/null` values.

Comment: Why is it needed to emit `<empty></empty>`?

Comment: I transform those XML files to human readable form using XSLT technology. I want to print `Field "empty": no content` instead of nothing. Those two information are completely different: `empty/null` vs `non-existent`.

Answer (score -1):

I needed to tackle the same issue, and here's how I got it working:

First I create a serializer that serializes nulls as empty string:

```java
public class NullAsEmptyStringSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

  static final JsonSerializer<Object> INSTANCE = new NullAsEmptyStringSerializer();

  private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";
  private final StringSerializer stringSerializer = new StringSerializer();

  @Override
  public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
      throws IOException {
    stringSerializer.serialize(EMPTY_STRING, gen, serializers);
  }
}
```

Then I create a serializer modifier, that overwrites the null serializer of the bean properties with my new serializer:

```java
public class NullToEmptyPropertySerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {

  @Override
  public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(SerializationConfig config,
      BeanDescription beanDesc, List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties) {
    for (BeanPropertyWriter beanProperty : beanProperties) {
      beanProperty.assignNullSerializer(NullAsEmptyStringSerializer.INSTANCE);
    }

    return beanProperties;
  }
}
```

And finally, I configure the xml mapper to use my modifier:

```java
NullToEmptyPropertySerializerModifier modifier = new NullToEmptyPropertySerializerModifier();
SerializerFactory serializerFactory = BeanSerializerFactory.instance.withSerializerModifier(modifier);
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.setSerializerFactory(serializerFactory);
```

Trying to see if it's working for strings and objects (`Person` and `Dog` are dummy data holder objects):

```
Dog dog = new Dog("bobby");
Person person = new Person("utku", null, 29, null);
String serialized = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(person);
System.out.println(serialized);
```

Gives the following output:

```xml
<Person><name>utku</name><address></address><age>29</age><dog></dog></Person>
```

Comment: I checked it and it doesn't work. The proposed code serializes `null` as element with empty value instead of empty element (`<element />` ← empty element, `<element></element>` ← element with an empty value). It also influences serialization of empty list and arrays - they are no long serialized to empty elements. Here is project used for testing: https://github.com/agabrys/bugs-reports/tree/master/jackson-xml/empty-elements-serialization/utku-proposal